# C# Entity Framework with Linq.Dynamic: ORDER BY COALESCE

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I got two tables, `dbo.Foo` and `dbo.Bar`.

`dbo.Foo` got two important properties:

- `ID` (Primary key)
- `OwnerID` (Foreign key to the same table (ID))

`dbo.Bar` got three important properties:

- `ID` (Primary key)
- `FooID` (Foreign key to `dbo.Foo` (ID))
- `FooOwnerID` (Foreign key to `dbo.Foo` (ID) too)

In `dbo.Bar`, `FooID` OR `FooOwnerID` has to be set. Below I created a graphic to show the structure:

[image: Data modell]

My model class for `dbo.Bar` looks like:

```
public class Bar
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int FooID { get; set; }
    public int FooOwnerID { get; set; }

    public virtual Foo Foo { get; set; }
    public virtual Foo FooOwner { get; set; }
}
```

The mapping for the table (using the fluent-api) looks like:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Bar>().ToTable("Bar", "dbo");
modelBuilder.Entity<Bar>().HasKey(x => x.ID);
modelBuilder.Entity<Bar>().Property(x => x.FooID).IsRequired();
modelBuilder.Entity<Bar>().Property(x => x.FooOwnerID).IsRequired();
modelBuilder.Entity<Bar>().HasOptional(x => x.Foo).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.FooID);
modelBuilder.Entity<Bar>().HasOptional(x => x.FooOwner).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.FooOwnerID);
```

This works. But I want to have `FooOwner` to be the actual owner of `Foo` instead of `null` if only `FooID` is set. Does someone have a idea how to do this?

**Background**

I am using DataTables to display the data at the view. To order the items, DataTables sends the name of the column to order (`Foo.ID` for example). I am using `Linq.Dynamic` to order the result set dynamically. An order string look like this: `Foo.ID asc, PropertyOfBar desc`.

Answer (score 0):

> Does someone have a idea how to do this?

Nothing built-in.  But you can always use a method or a NotMapped property

eg

```
public Foo GetFooOwner() => FooOwner??Foo.Owner;
```

Comment: Yeah, I know this, but with that its not possible to let the SQL server perform the sorting. I want to get something like the following SQL query:

`SELECT * FROM dbo.Bar LEFT JOIN dbo.Foo AS Foo ON Foo.ID = dbo.Bar.FooID INNER JOIN dbo.Foo as FooOwner ON FooOwner.ID =           COALESCE(Foo.OwnerID, dbo.Bar.FooOwnerID) ORDER BY {DYNAMIC STRING}`